# Linux Mint 18.1. How download latest Gradle version?

Tags: linux-mint

Linux Mint 18.1.

When I go to Software Manager I found Gradle ver. 2.10. 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGZ9l.png)

But it's old version. Current version of Gradle is 4.0.
How I can download latest version of Gradle?

Answer (score 3):

This [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/975018) shows a way to accomplish this with Personal Package Archive (PPA) and it works with Mint as well (tested on Mint 18.2). Steps taken directly from the answer:

1. Add the package repository
2. Update package list
3. Install Gradle

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade gradle
   ```